# I built Chromium for Android but sync doesn't work

Tags: android, build, chromium

I built Android Chromium with arguments

```
google_api_key = "your_api_key"
google_default_client_id = "your_client_id"
google_default_client_secret = "your_client_secret"
```

but sync does not work. I can give my account but I get message: "Sync isn't working Sign in again to start sync" But it never works...
I added my email address to chromium-dev@chromium.org and google-browser-signin-testaccounts@chromium.org as is suggested in https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys

I also did everything the above link suggests, I enabled the Google APIs etc..

Any help?
Thank you!

Comment: Chrome sync API is now private past March 15, 2021 , so you shouldn't be using it. More info: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/embedder-dev/c/NXm7GIKTNTE

Comment: Here https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys it says: "  In order to sign in to Chromium builds, please add your test account to google-browser-signin-testaccounts@chromium.org (accounts in this group are allowed to get access tokens bypassing the restriction above)." So I understand that I could use it.